# How should i save the response data in a object(json) to have better manipulation and performance?

Tags: javascript, json, optimization

what i am doing is:

**1.** Get values from ajax response(which is in json format) for listing rows of data which

```
response = {"categories":[{"name":"General","id":"6305","pop":"show when clicked"},{"name":"Navigation","id":"6043","pop":"show when clicked"},{"name":"New","id":"6051","pop":"show when clicked"},{"name":"Time","id":"6117","pop":"show when clicked"},{"name":"Reesh","id":"6207","pop":"show when clicked"}]}
```

**2** . I will  parse the json and store in a object like this

ex:

```
object= {6305:{"name":"General","id":"6305","pop":"show when clicked"},
6043:{"name":"Navigation","id":"6043","pop":"show when clicked"},
6051:{"name":"New","id":"6051","pop":"show when clicked"},
6117:{"name":"Time","id":"6117","pop":"show when clicked"},
6207:{"name":"Reesh","id":"6207","pop":"show when clicked"}};
```

why i am doing this is because i can get the data using the id

ex: object[6305] will give me the data.

**3** .So that i can retrieve the data and also make changes to values in the object using the id when changes occur in db.

ex: object[6350].pop="changed";

**Please tell me:**

-->whether is this the **correct method** or i can do it **in a much simpler or efficient way**?

-->whether i can store the json response as it is and parse data as it is? if so **please explain with example.**

Comment: I do always store JSON as objects. What are your other options? Parsing a string every time you need to access/modify data? Sure that could save some bytes in the memory but it adds too much processing overhead and extra code to be worth it IMO.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté : hi i just want to know instead of storing a (6305:{"name":"General","id":"6305","pop":"show when clicked"}) can i store as ({"name":"General","id":"6305","pop":"show when clicked"},{"name":"General","id":"6305","pop":"show when clicked")) and access the data with id

Comment: @FabrícioMatté : because in ui i store the id in the html element, and when i click the element i must show the details stored in the object. i just want to know the best way to do in such situation. currently im doing as explained in the question. :)

Comment: I see. Apart from the outer parens `()` which seem to be a typo, using `{}` will make an object with numerical properties that work like you described. There are other ways to store the data, for example, you could use `data-pop="show when clicked"` then retrieve it with `$(this).data('pop')` inside a click handler of an element, for example. This way would mix a lot of data into your HTML though, so your way of having a JSON object seems more organized.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté : i did not want to store the data in html element, because i wanted to access those data easily by giving the id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, of course you would not need to build the `object`:

```
function getObject(id) {
    for (var i=0; i<response.categories.length; i++)
        if (response.categories[i].id == id)
            return response.categories[i];
    return null;
}
```

However, if you often need to access objects by their ids this function would be slow. Creating the lookup table as you did will not create much memory overhead, but make retrieving data much faster.

BTW: Your title question "*save data as object or json*" is confusing. Serializing manipulated objects back to JSON makes no sense, as you always will use the parsed objects. Of course, if you just needed to manipulate a JSON string, and knew exactly what to do, (simple) string manipulation *could* be faster than parsing, manipulating and stringifying.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i will be accessing the objects often by their id. so i will be using "object" as a lookup table. :)